# Where is the implementation of Cursor

Tags: android, cursor

I read android sources for fun,

and i want to see how the cursor class is implemented, i went to the sources folder and found only the interfaces for it.

Where is the actual code ?

Answer (score 2):

Look at [SQLiteCursor](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteCursor.html) .

Also, here is the link to [android Cursor implementation list](http://book2s.com/java/api/android/database/cursor/cursor-implement.html) .

Answer (score 0):

`Cursor` is an interface, not a class. [Here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/database/Cursor.java) is the source code.

**EDIT IN RESPONSE TO COMMENT**

I assume you mean [this](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.1_r2/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.java): look at the `query` method. It returns a `Cursor` instance for a particular `SQLiteDatabase`.

Comment: I already read that, i meant where is the implementation that is returned by a normal query to the SQLiteDatabase ?

Comment: where is the implementation for this: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.1_r2/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteCursorDriver.java#SQLiteCursorDriver.query%28android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory%2Cjava.lang.String%5B%5D%29

Comment: Again, that's an interface. Thus it is used by classes to define it's methods. There is no single implementation of it.

Comment: @LenaBru You are confusing between a normal class and an interface. Please clear your basics first.

Comment: @RohanKandwal you are confusing between what i am asking and what you think i am asking. There is some class out there that has public class someName implements Cursor , and that is the one returned by my request to the database to query it, do you know of such a class ?

Comment: @LenaBru Sorry I don't